# WebApi controller view is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2015

- created a web application using mvc template and checked web api and mvc
- added ado.net model
- created web api controller with actions using entity framework
- scaffolding view for 'create' from web api controller
- create.cshtml is created

When create.cshtml is ran, this error occurs:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.  Requested URL: /Fruit/Create
>
> Folder route: Views/Fruit/Create

Comment: Is `FruitController` is a webapi controller?

Comment: Please post the relevant code otherwise it's impossible help. Does your `FruitController` class have a `Create` method? If it doesn't then it doesn't matter whether you have a view or not

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the route.

there is sometimes like :

```
api/controller/action
```

open *WebApiConfig.cs*

you may have this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

which sends your request to

```
api/Fruit/Create
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check first "**WebApiConfig**" in api Like:

---

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Answer (score 0):

The first major thing you have to be aware of is that actions on Web-API controllers returns data not the views.

You've to return view from an MVC controller and then invoke web api from the view after it is returned.